# How to add a JS library and a JS script that makes use of that library?

Tags: javascript, requirejs, requirejs-config.js

I'm trying to use [Chroma](https://gka.github.io/chroma.js/) library in Magento and so far I did the following two things:

1. Created a app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/requirejs-config.js with the following content:

```
var config = {
deps: [
'js/chroma.min',
'js/_sample',
]
};
```

and a _sample.js file in app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/web/js/_sample.js
with the following code:

```
chromaColor = chroma.random();
```

A pretty straightforward and simple thing to do, but in the browser while both scripts load just fine, _sample.js throws this error: *Can't find variable: chroma*.

Somehow my _sample.js just doesn't seem to have access to the Chroma library? Or is it something else? Am I including those files wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var config = {
    paths: {
        "chroma": "js/chroma.min",
        "sampleJs": "js/_sample"
    },
    shim: {
        sampleJs: {
            deps: ['chroma']
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: No, same thing. I did setup:upgrade and Magento's seeing the changes. Still can't find that "variable".

Comment: Wait, chroma.min isn't being loaded, at least I don't see it in the browser. _sample.js however does get loaded. Weird.

Comment: do you have minification enabled? you may want to double-check your error console for  'chroma.min'

Comment: Not sure about what you mean by "minification enabled", chroma itself is minified... But the console is totally silent about chroma.min.js, I've seen errors before that it can't load it for some reason (path wrong for example) but now it appears that it's not trying to load at all. It also stopped appearing in Sources (in Safari) that list all the js files for the page.

Comment: What mode is your Magento store in default, developer, or production?

Comment: Current application mode: default.

Comment: Check to see if chroma.min exists in pub/static/frontend/Vendor/Theme/en_US/js

Comment: Yes, it's present there. I can even open its source in browser if I go to the URL where it's supposed to be (same path as _sample.js).

Comment: It's a bit odd. After I do setup:static-content:deploy -f, the js is there (but still not loaded), afterwards when I do setup:upgrade, it disappears.

Comment: Check to see if the above config was added to requireJs config. ``http://site.test/static/version1656248217/frontend/Vendor/Theme/en_US/requirejs-config.js``

Comment: Yes, I can see the snippet there, right at the end. And I can also see the snippet in the browser while viewing requirejs-config.js contents in Sources tab on the main store page.